# Failed to create user in keycloak , User creation response body: {"error":"unkown error."}

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

i'm trying to create new users with spring boot and keycloak, but the creation always fail, the error that i get is "unkown error"
this is the keycloak configuration:

```
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuerUri;

    @Bean
    public Keycloak keycloak() {
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/auth")
                .realm("lbv-realm")
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .clientId("auth-client")
                .clientSecret("VHqrOzv6X9QeenxlyOTBN8ZCbqusZubD")
                .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
                .build();
    }
```

and this is the create function

```
    public void createUser(RegisterRequest userDto) {
        RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(realmName);
        UsersResource usersResource = realmResource.users();

        UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
        user.setUsername(userDto.getUsername());
        user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
        user.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstname());
        user.setLastName(userDto.getLastname());
        user.setEnabled(true);
        Response response = usersResource.create(user);
        if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
            String responseBody = response.readEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("User creation response body: " + responseBody);
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create user");
        }

        String userId = CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response);
        System.out.println("Created user with ID: " + userId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with assigning the right role to the client i'm using, so i needed to assign the role 'manage-user' , but i couldn't find it in my keycloak version 21 , and this is how i was able to :
.Go to Clients, access my client
.Go to the Service Account Roles tab
.then click on Assign Role
.Filter by "clients" (default is by "realm roles")
.then search by the desired role, in the correct realm (e.g. manage-users)
.Select the role and click on Assign
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuIY2.png)